How to run multiple Feature files parallelly in Cucumber with TestNG Runner?
I am facing one issue: I need to run 5 feature files that are totally independent of each other, Each feature files logs into a different site. I want 5 different ChromeDriver Browser sessions to open and all scenarios in all feature files should run parallelly and then once all scenarios are done, single Extent report should be generated once.
But I cant run, logs are written side by side in Eclipse console and its all messed up.  Can you help me write runner class code? Do i need to create multiple runner classes or change Maven surefire plugin thread count and parallel=tests or classes?
Also, issue is that userid and password are copied as one single string in userid textbox. Ex: 23423adminpassword22 is copied in userid text box itself
  @Login
  Scenario Outline: Perform Standard login in portal
    Given Open site with url "<url>" and browser "<browser>"
    Then Enter login credentials for "<portalID>" and "<userID>" and "<password>"
    Then Successfully logged in to portal

    Examples: 
      | portalID| userID | password  | url                       | browser |
      |     23423| admin  | password22 | https://testsite.com | chrome  |

TestRunner class(Cucumber with TestNG)
@CucumberOptions(glue = { "stepDefinitions" }, features = { "src/test/resources/features" })

public class TestRunner {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber scenarios", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void scenario(PickleWrapper pickleEvent, FeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }

}

POM.XML File:
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc42 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>tests</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>20</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

TestNG.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

